# Why can't I make a proper SQL/PHP query using javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to make a query to an SQL database and I can't figure out why my code won't work. When I call the javascript function:

```
function calledfunction(){
var date = new Date(document.getElementById("datetime1").value);
var dateformat = "'"+date.getFullYear() + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "-" + date.getDate() + " " + date.getHours() +":" + date.getMinutes()+"'";
        alert("Value is: " + dateformat);
                microAjax("genjsonphp.php?stdt="+dateformat, function(data) {
                     //edited out
      }
```

I get the alert: Value is: '2011-12-6 0:0'

When I copy the value in the alert and paste it so the above code becomes:

```
function calledfunction(){
var date = new Date(document.getElementById("datetime1").value);
var dateformat = "'"+date.getFullYear() + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "-" + date.getDate() + " " + date.getHours() +":" + date.getMinutes()+"'";
        alert("Value is: " + dateformat);
dateformat = '2011-12-6 0:0';

                microAjax("genjsonphp.php?stdt="+dateformat, function(data) {
                     //edited out
      }
```

Then the code works fine. Does anyone have an idea what is going wrong?

Comment: As a side note, I think you should make your query string more URL "formatty". It might mess up your ajax otherwise `microAjax("genjsonphp.php?stdt="+encodeURIComponent(dateformat), function(){});`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're explicitly quoting the variable string:

```
 "'"+date.getFullYear() ...
```

so you're sending

```
genjsonphp.php?stdt='2011-12-6 0:0'
```

(note the single quotes)

In the second case you're sending:

```
genjsonphp.php?stdt=2011-12-6 0:0
```

Comment: console.log the url's and you will see that Alex K. is correct.

Comment: so, var dateformat = '2011-12-6 0:0'; and var dateformat = "'"+date.getFullYear() + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "-" + date.getDate() + " " + date.getHours() +":" + date.getMinutes()+"'"; do not produce the same thing?

Comment: Nope; `var X = 'A'` is the 1 character string `A` whereas `var X = "'" + 'A' + "'" is` the 3 character long string `'A'`

Answer (score 1):

this `"genjsonphp.php?stdt="+'2011-12-6 0:0'` parses to: `"genjsonphp.php?stdt=2011-12-6 0:0"`
while `"genjsonphp.php?stdt="+dateformat` parses to: `"genjsonphp.php?stdt='2011-12-6 0:0'"`

Watch the quotes.